# Remove App Launcher from Main Navigation Menu in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, app-launcher

How can I remove or disable the **App Launcher** from navigation menu?
[image]

Comment: Really would have thought there was an answer to this by now. Salesforce only cares to post how to enable it but it seems it's enabled by default with no way to turn off even then I reverse engineer their instruction to enable it: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/identity_app_launcher_profile.htm :/